# How to iterate through a List of Arrays of Objects C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops, collision-detection

I'm building a 2D physics simulation, and am currently working on the collision detection between rotating squares.

My collision detection algorithm works like this:

- Broad phase

  - Check if Boxes' axis-aligned bounding box are overlapping
  - If so put the 2 boxes that are overlapping into a 2 element array, and put this array in a list (broadPhaseCollisionList)
- Narrow phase

  - Loop through broadPhaseCollisionList and examine the collisions (represented by a Box[]) to tell if they're actually colliding

The problem is that the first Console.WriteLine() prints out the correct Box indexes, but the second Console.WriteLine() always prints out "ObserverBox: 2 ObservedBox: 3" when there is a broad-phase collision.

Here is my code:

```
        //set all boxes to "not colliding"
        foreach (Box box in boxList)
        {
            box.colliding = false;
        }

        List<Box[]> broadPhaseCollisionList = new List<Box[]>();
        Box[] collisionPair = new Box[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < boxList.Count; i++)
        {
            Box observerBox = boxList[i];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < boxList.Count; j++)
            {
                Box observedBox = boxList[j];

                if (observerBox != observedBox)
                {
                    collisionPair[0] = observerBox;
                    collisionPair[1] = observedBox;

                    if (TestAABBOverlap(observerBox.aabb, observedBox.aabb))
                    {
                        observerBox.colliding = true;
                        observedBox.colliding = true;

                        broadPhaseCollisionList.Add(collisionPair);
                        //timer.Stop();
                        Box[] box = broadPhaseCollisionList[0];
                        Console.WriteLine("ObserverBox: " + box[0].index + " ObservedBox: " + box[1].index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < broadPhaseCollisionList.Count; i++)
        {
            Box[] collision = broadPhaseCollisionList[i];
            Box observerBox = collision[0];
            Box observedBox = collision[1];

            Console.WriteLine("ObserverBox: " + observerBox.index + " ObservedBox: " + observedBox.index);
            Console.WriteLine("/-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: `Box[] box = broadPhaseCollisionList[0];` however many times you add, you always pick the first item from the list.

Comment: @RufusL This code throws no exceptions, and the index is hard coded there because I am only testing this with one collision at a time so I only want to examine broadPhaseCollisionList[0].

Comment: Please show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the class definition of `Box`.

Comment: @Sach I only want to pick the first collision in the list because I am currently only testing this in cases where there is only one collision. Also it does compile and runs seemingly fine apart from the issue in my question...

Comment: Like I said, please provide an MCVE, otherwise we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: `broadPhaseCollisionList[0]` will always be the same (first) collision pair on every iteration. Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you should either output `collisionPair[0]` and `collisionPari[1]` or use `broadPhaseCollisionList[broadPhaseCollisionList.Count - 1]` if you want to show the collision pair that was just detected

Comment: Also, unrelated tip, but your `observerBox != observedBox` line will never evaluate to `false`. In other words, those two objects will never be equal even if all their properties are the same. To see if two class objects are equal you'll need to write a custom comparer.

Comment: @Sach I'm struggling to work out how to make this minimal but I have included the definition for Box in the question. Also thanks for the tip that's a good spot!

Comment: @RufusL Yes because I am only testing it with one collision, but no matter what boxes the collision is between, the second WriteLine always outputs 2 and 3

Comment: Almost there. Please also show how you're initializing/populating `boxList` in your main code.

Comment: @Sach I have just added that info to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that you're only adding a reference to the `collisionPair` array to your `broadPhaseCollisionList` on each iteration (you're adding the same reference over and over).  Meanwhile, the `collisionPair` items are getting updated with the latest collision on each iteration.

At the end of your loop, `collisionPair` contains the last collision pair, and `broadPhaseCollisionList` contains [collisionCount] items all pointing to the same array.

To fix this, you should set `collisionPair` to a **new** array each time before adding it to your list:

```
if (observerBox != observedBox && TestAABBOverlap(observerBox.aabb, observedBox.aabb))
{
    observerBox.colliding = true;
    observedBox.colliding = true;

    broadPhaseCollisionList.Add(new[] {observedBox, observerBox});
```

Comment: Nice. You beat me to it.

Comment: That's great, cheers! Shall I remove the extra info from my question now?

Comment: Sure, glad it helped. I also updated it with some more concise syntax. And yeah, I guess the extra information turned out to not be necessary for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're always writing the values of box[0] and box[1].
Your line should probably be:

```
Console.WriteLine("ObserverBox: " + observerBox.index + " ObservedBox: " + observedBox.index);
```

Comment: There, box should probably have been written as collision, because really it is a two element array with element [0] being the observerBox and [1] being the observedBox. That line will produce the same output.

Answer (score -1):

You have to drill down.

```
broadPhaseCollisionList[i].observerBox[0].ToString()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at here, that expression doesn't work